# Xpath command in importXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I need a some help in getting a ImportXML command to return the result I'm looking for.
I'm using Google Sheets.

The XML I'm using looks like this:

```
<DocumentElement>
    <BuyOrder>
        <itemName>Name of item 1</itemname>
        <itemID>1</itemID>
        <maxPrice>1000</maxPrice>
        <quantity>100</quantity>
    </BuyOrder>
    <BuyOrder>
        <itemName>Name of item 2</itemname>
        <itemID>2</itemID>
        <maxPrice>2000</maxPrice>
        <quantity>200</quantity>
    </BuyOrder>
</DocumentElement>
```

And so on.

What I need is an XPath expression I can use to get `maxPrice` on a specific `itemID`.
The ID for `itemID` comes from another cell in the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this xpath will help you

```
xpath = "//itemID[contains(.,'1')]/following-sibling::maxPrice"
```

Comment: Better to use this xpath = "//itemID[contains(.,1)]/following-sibling::maxPrice" instead of the previous one as contains(.,'1') selects both nodes.
<itemId>1<itemId>
<itemId>11<itemId>

Comment: well @ArtjomB. what if nodes are like 



   ......

   <ItemID>11</ItemID>

   <maxPrice>100</maxPrice>

   ....

   <ItemID>1</ItemID>

   <maxPrice>100000</maxPrice>

   ....

Comment: The string: "//itemID[contains(.,1)]/following-sibling::maxPrice[1]" is diffinately very close to what I needed. I only have 2 follow up issues :) <-p> If I change the 1 to the ID I need the information from, I do in some instances get two results back. E.g a id of 258 would also return the value from 12258 which off course isn't want I want. <br> Secondly can I get the value in the contains string from a cell in the sheet? Like contains(.,B2) for cell B2?

Comment: @user3832656 If you get two nodes from the call then you probably have a problem with your data (same `itemID` used twice). You can use `contains(.,B2)`, but I don't see how you would benefit from that. Previously I missed that everything is inside `BuyOrder` so there is no need for `[1]` in `following-sibling::maxPrice[1]`.

Comment: @user3832656 just pass ID as a integer instead of a string Eg in ruby language "//itemID[contains(.,#{ID.to_i})]/following-sibling::maxPrice"  will give you correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
//DocumentElement/BuyOrder[itemID=2]/maxPrice
```

http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp has some nice examples for learning XPath. they also have an online XPath tester.

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath is another online XPath tester.

Comment: You should really quote the text: `[itemID="2"]`